# What should our Easter egg be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Most StackExchange websites (even some currently in beta) have some sort of Easter egg.  These are usually applied to the chat room, so that when you send a specially-crafted message the chat room does something interesting.

Some examples:

RPG has dice.
[image]
SuperUser has Clippy.
[image]
Gaming has Asteroids.
[image]
ServerFault has `rm -rf /`.
[image]

And there are some others, [documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75861/what-easter-eggs-do-the-chat-sites-have) and undocumented.

Our regular chat crowd has yet to stumble across any for our site, so we're guessing there either isn't one or we're just not being told.  Under the former presumption, I'd like to suggest that we put some proposals here.  I'm not aware of whether or not the communities actually get to choose their Easter egg, but I figured we could at least make sure there's some input available for whenever SEI decides to give us one.

So, what Easter egg would you like to see?  Only one suggestion per answer, please, to allow for voting to be accurate.

Comment: I'd say explicitly no easteregg here as it is totally wrong in mind of security.

Comment: @ordag Damn.  CM-07 finally bites me in the ass.

Answer (score 14):

Faux SQL-Injection vectors.

(I.e. simulated results for certain sqli commands, such as `' or ''='` or `select * from users where 1=1`, etc)

Answer (score 12):

**Easter Egg Scenario:** Just type **`Global Thermonuclear War`**... then the user hits enter, and [gets something like this animation](http://www.globalthermonuclearwar.net/launch/index.html), followed by a link to the YouTube [SHALL WE PLAY A GAME?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLJ3zcdPtl8&t=4m23s)

---

[image]

Comment: How about a nice game of chess?

Comment: +1 @Iszi: So, do you know how to get Stack Exchange to add an Easter Egg?

Comment: I think this would be made even more fun if, once the message pops up, a world map shows which you can click on to fire nukes at.

Comment: @Polynomia: Guess I disagree. The point is to reproduce the feeling of the movie, not make the event into a game -- after all, "The only winning move is not to play. How about a [nice game of chess](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/420/pawn-to-queen-probabilities-chart)?"

Comment: @blunders Good point, actually :P

Answer (score 11):

If we go for xkcd, i'd suggest Bobby Tables instead of sudo:

[image]

Comment: Oh, yeah!  Fake a SQL injection response?  I like it.

Answer (score 10):

An animated bear (possible Winnie the Pooh, possible a ravenous grizzly with laser eyes and adamantium fangs) strolls across the screen to eat a target gravatar

Comment: +1 @Rory Alsop: So, are we going to move forward with asking SE if it's possible to deploy your idea? Thanks! (Ask in part because the question is slowly dropping off the active questions list, and the answers and votes appear to be pretty stable now.) Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Replace all gravatars with [Guy Fawkes Mask](http://timdunn.deviantart.com/art/Guy-Fawkes-Mask-vectorised-138614344) if question is tagged with "hacking".

Answer (score 6):

How about some `sudo` commands, a-la [XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/149/):

[image]

Comment: Did you know python 3 has `import antigravity` ?

Comment: @user2213: Nice. Did you know about `import this`?

Answer (score 4):

Not really chat-specific, but this would be really cool:

Implement site-wide HTTPS support for IT Security SE sites (main, blog, meta, chat).  Of course, it would be ideal for this to be done across all SE sites.  But if that's not an option, I think it would be cool if we could stand out as being the one that does have it.

Comment: Not really an easter-egg too. Think we could suggest this as a real feature request somewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's already been suggested and shot down on [meta.SE], if not even here.  I just thought I'd toss it in here as another idea to make our site more unique.

Comment: Perhaps it was shot down if the advertisements don't send over HTTPS ... thus a mixed content warning

Comment: (being implemented now)

Answer (score 3):

How about the classic ping-pong virus?

Answer (score 1):

images of easter eggs with the OWASP top 10 writen on them

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set up a regex that will trigger auto-generation of a Nigerian Prince (or maybe an assortment of other) e-mail scam, with user-chosen content included.

Answer (score 0):

A "man in the middle" that changes your text that you type into the chatroom.

Perhaps call the MITM individual [Mallory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob)

Comment: Though this may be better suited for Crypto.SE

Answer (score 0):

A fake ransomware maybe? It's Easter but we have no Easter egg yet.

Answer (score -1):

Add some trigger to pop-up a fake AV alert to some (or all) user(s) in the room.

Comment: You can't have an esater egg that bother someone else.

Comment: @M'vy: Yeah, you can't. We have one in our company-internal rooms though :)