# Easter Egg: Can we onebox Tumblr in our chatroom?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat

[Security Reactions](http://securityreactions.tumblr.com/) is a picture blog that has become very popular in the sec.se community lately, it basically consists of a caption denoting a very common scenario for security professionals, and a visual image describing the situation, or our typical reactions to it.
It is often the group reaction in the DMZ, too, to posts on the site.

It would be very useful, not to mention very cool, if a link to a specific secreactions post were to be transformed, in typical OneBox fashion (only for [Security.SE] chatrooms, or specifically the DMZ), to a caption and image.

For example, [this link](http://securityreactions.tumblr.com/post/33891938791/but-we-sanitize-input-with-javascript): `http://securityreactions.tumblr.com/post/33891938791/but-we-sanitize-input-with-javascript` would be oneboxed to

> “…But we sanitize input with Javascript!”
>   [image]

---

Barring that, could we get one of the [other easter eggs suggested](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/692/33)?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. Needs to be done!

Comment: Another mod saying yes.

Comment: I mentioned this to **Marc Gravell**. He said he and **balpha** will look into it. I'll provide information when I have it. :)

Comment: yay! @Aarthi rules!

Comment: :D I'm basically the best. (Kidding, but the love is appreciated nevertheless. :D)

Comment: @Aarthi - distance is a challenge, but will hugs do :-)

Comment: Yes, tumblr oneboxing is necessary on all the chat rooms, so that these fine pages onebox: http://whatbikeracersshouldcallme.tumblr.com/post/34740111916/when-your-teammate-doesnt-want-to-stop-to-eat-after-a  http://whatbikeracersshouldcallme.tumblr.com/post/34864781429/the-hardest-decision-to-make-after-a-ride  http://whatbikeracersshouldcallme.tumblr.com/post/35105205123/racing-in-the-rain

Comment: @freiheit - I love that 3rd one!

Answer (score 8):

So after talking to Marc about this for a while this morning, here's the key takeaways:

- This would be a **nontrivial** task, and we're stretched a bit thin on dev resources right now. There's just a lot on their plates and quite a bit in the proverbial queue.
- That said: this **is something we want** to do. A lot of our emergency/backup communications are hosted on Tumblr, so supporting Tumblr oneboxing is useful for us!
- In my personal opinion, we try to support nifty things for the companies in our venture capital portfolio, which Tumblr is part of. So, this is a **natural and precedented** thing for us to support.

We'll come back to this, and I'll update this answer once I get more news/updates. Otherwise, consider this On The Big List for now!

Comment: A programmer used the phrase "nontrivial"? All right everybody, now drink.

Comment: Yay - a round of drinks for everyone! And a round of hugs for @Aarthi!